# VMware Studio: create Ubuntu 64bit virtual appliance

Tags: ubuntu, 64-bit, virtualization

I'm using VMware Studio 2 to create virtual appliances.
Now we want to make an appliance of a 64 bit Ubuntu distro, but it's not in the template list, like Redhat 64bit and CentOS 64bit.
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There should be an option saying something like "DEB" or "Debian" as opposed to the RPM builds for the RHEL/CentOS ones you've already done, that's certainly how you do it from a command line.

[Here's](http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/studio/studio20/studio_developer.pdf) a link to the dev guide.

Answer (score 0):

Use a generic Linux 64